# Guava cache considering older key

Tags: java, caching, guava, google-guava-cache

I am facing an issue with Guava Caches. When I have only one element in cache, things are fine. But when I load a second element, Its trying to pick with key of earlier entry

```
private static LoadingCache<String, MyClass> cache = null;
....
public MyClass method(final String id1, final long id2)  {
    log.error("inside with "+id1);
    final String cacheKey = id1+"-"+id2;
    if(cache == null){
        cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
       .maximumSize(1000)
       .build(
            new CacheLoader<String, MyClass>() {
                @Override
                public MyClass load(String key) {
                    return getValue(cacheKey);
                }
           }
        );
    }
    try {
        return cache.get(cacheKey);
    } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
        log.error("EEE missing entry",ex);
    }
}

private MyClass getValue(String cacheKey){
    log.error("not from cache "+cacheKey);
    ...

}
```

The log says:

```
inside with 129890038707408035563943963861595603358
not from cache 1663659699-315839912047403113610285801857400882820 // This is key for the earlier entry
```

For eg, When I call method("1", 2), it loads the value in cache and I am able to get it from cache subsequently. Now I call method ("3", 4), this is not in cache, so getValue() is called and the log prints out the key for method("1", 2)

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: which key ? please provide full steps to reproduce

Comment: please note that the way you initialize your cache is not thread safe. Moreover it is a static cache using a CacheLoader based on a non static method which sounds like a very bad approach, much too error prone. I believe that your mistake is probably due to one of those things

Comment: Please read this rule (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: When I call method("1", 2), it loads the value in cache and I am able to get it from cache subsequently. Now I call method ("3", 4), this is not in cache, so getValue() is called and the log prints out the key for method("1", 2)

Comment: please add it in your question description not as comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is related to how you create your `CacheLoader`, if you check well you will see that you initialize it with a given cache key (the value of the local variable `cacheKey` at the time the cache is lazily initialized) while it should be more generic and rely on the `key` provided as parameter to the method `load` of your `CacheLoader` otherwise it will load the cache by calling `getValue(key)` with the same key.

It should be this:

```
new CacheLoader<String, MyClass>() {
    @Override
    public MyClass load(String key) {
        return getValue(key); // instead of return getValue(cacheKey);
    }
}
```

---

**NB:** The way you initialize your cache is **not thread safe**, indeed if it has not been initialized and your method `method` is called by several threads concurrently it will be created several times instead of one.

One way could be to use the double-checked locking idiom as next:

```
private static volatile LoadingCache<String, MyClass> cache = null;
public MyClass method(final String id1, final long id2)  {
    ...
    if(cache == null){
        synchronized (MyClass.class) {
            if(cache == null){
                cache = ...
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**NB:** Do not initialize a **static** cache with a `CacheLoader` based on a **non static** method, it is much too error prone. Make them both **non static** or **static** but don't mix them.

Assuming that you can make both **static**, your cache initialization will be very simply, it would simply be:

```
private static final LoadingCache<String, MyClass> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()...
```

No need to initialize it lazily which will also simplify a lot the code of your method as it will simply be reduce to:

```
public MyClass method(final String id1, final long id2)  {
    log.error("inside with "+id1);
    final String cacheKey = id1+"-"+id2;
    try {
        return cache.get(cacheKey);
    } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
        log.error("EEE missing entry",ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also consider `Suppliers.memoize` to encapsulate the double-checked locking idiom

Comment: Could test this only now, Thanks a lot